# Inverse grep using a pattern file doesn't show non-matches

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep

I have two nearly identical files, ["foo" and "bar"](http://ge.tt/9fggge53).

Each file has thousands of lines, one number each line.

If I `sort` and then `diff` both files, this is the result:

```
$ diff foo bar
5984a5985,5986
> 15676
> 15677
7703,7706d7704
< 17486
< 17487
< 17488
< 17489
```

However, if I `grep -Fvf` both files, I get zero "non-matches" in both directions:

```
$ grep -Fvf foo bar
$ grep -Fvf bar foo
$
```

Why is that? Shouldn't I be getting results similar to diff? I'd expect the first command to return me the "first half" of the values on diff, and the second grep command to return me the rest.

Why am I not getting the expected results?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For `diff`, unlike `grep -Fvf`, *the order that lines appear matters*.  Also, since the `-x` option was not included in the grep command,  lines with mere *partial matches* are excluded from the output.

#### Reproducible example

Consider these two files:

```
$ cat foo
156
174
15676
17486
17487
$ cat bar
15677
15678
156
174
15676
```

The `diff` command shows they are different while the `grep` commands produce no output:

```
$ diff foo bar
0a1,2
> 15677
> 15678
4,5d5
< 17486
< 17487
$ grep -Fvf foo bar; grep -Fvf bar foo
```

If we were to add `-x` to require full-line matches, then grep produces:

```
$ grep -Fvxf foo bar
15677
15678
$ grep -Fvxf bar foo
17486
17487
```

#### Additional suggestion

As [abligh](https://superuser.com/users/302893/abligh) suggests in the comments, `diff -u` produces more context which can make the output easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks **a lot**! 

Comment: I'd add `diff -u` rather than `diff` generally makes it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: @abligh Good suggestion.  I just added mention of the `-u` option to the end of the answer.